# How to control loading order when mixing auto-configure and component scan in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

The user story is like this:

We have exposed some APIs through library jars which use the Spring Boot auto-configure mechanism. The APIs need some glue logic during initialization, so we put them under **@PostConstruct** block of some **@Configuration**s and register them as auto-configured.

The user code is based on **@SpringBootApplication**, while they prefer to use **@ComponentScan** to define beans instead auto-configure.

So the issue comes, Spring always tries to load the beans defined by **@ComponentScan** first, then those auto-configured beans. So if any user bean relies on the API that not been initialized, it sure will fail.

It seems there's no way to define the bean order when mixing the auto-configured and component-scanned beans. The **@Order, @AutoConfigureOrder, @AutoConfigureAfter, @AutoConfigureBefore** annotation and Ordered interface only work among all auto configured beans.

Of course if user uses auto-configure for their beans too, it will work without problem. But from user's perspective, **@ComponentScan** looks a more natural and easier way, especially **@SpringBootApplication** implies the **@ComponentScan** of current java package.

Our current workaround is to eager load those API initialization configures at a very-early stage. For web context, it's **ServletContextInitializer.onStartup()**, and for other generic context, it's **LoadTimeWeaverAware's @PostConstruct**.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class EagerInitWebContextInitializer implements ServletContextInitializer, PriorityOrdered 
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        String[] beanNames = appContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(EagerInitializer.class);

        if (beanNames != null) {
            // pre-load all eager initializers
            for (String name : beanNames) {
                appContext.getBean(name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
}

@Configuration
@ConditionalOnNotWebApplication
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class EagerInitGenericContextInitializer implements LoadTimeWeaverAware, PriorityOrdered 
{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        String[] beanNames = appContext.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(EagerInitializer.class);

        if (beanNames != null) {
            // pre-load all eager initializers
            for (String name : beanNames) {
                appContext.getBean(name);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLoadTimeWeaver(LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver) {
        // does nothing
    }
}
```

This actually works well. But just wondering is there any better way to achieve this or whether future Spring version can provide a similar systematic way?

Comment: You should take a look on `@DependsOn` anotation.

Comment: The idea is user code should only focus on the API, the API may be exposed through beans or regular POJO. Those glue logic in the configuration is more like internal things and should be hidden to user code.